# Qualitatively how does the O-wind turbine function?

Tags: renewable-energy

Recently the O-wind turbine won the James Dyson award for innovation, the item is essentially a compact wind turbine which unlike traditional wind turbines can harness wind from multiple directions, the wind is converted to kinetic energy to then generate electrical energy.

However I am struggling to understand how this works as a concept. From what I've read the spherical shape is fitted with vents which has a large entrance hole and small exit holes. I am unsure of how this could initiate the movement of the object in the presence of wind.

Answer (score 1):

Taken directly from the [James Dyson Award](https://www.jamesdysonaward.org/2018/project/o-wind-turbine/) website.

**How it Works**

"The turbine is of a spherical shape with a single axis of rotation going through it. Its dimensions and shape mean that it is very suitable for small-scale energy production by individual apartment dwellers e.g. by being fixed outside balconies.

The turbine makes use of Bernoulli’s principle for its mechanical motion. The structure is lined up with vents which have large entrances and smaller exits for air. In the presence of wind, there is a pressure difference between the two terminals causing the turbine to move. The vents are placed all across the sphere making it receptive to wind from all directions in both the vertical and horizontal planes.

The turbine will rotate in the same sense about a fixed axis regardless of wind direction. This turbine rotation is used to power a generator that can produce electricity, which can be fed into the national grid, hence providing financial incentive to users and improving the region’s sustainable energy production. "